# How to add line numbers in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, string-formatting, enumerate

I have a list and I want to add count numbers.

```
list1 = ['John', 'Maria',',','and','Danny', 'are','#','1','surfers','.']
```

I want my output to look like.

> 1. John
> 2. Maria
> 3. ,
> 4. and
> 5. Danny
> 6. are
> 7. #
> 8. 1
> 9. surfers
> 10. .

My code looks like this. I cannot use any libraries.

```
count = 1
for count,a in enumerate(list1):
     count += 1
print("{0}{1}".format(count, a))
```

Comment: Out of interest, *why* can't you use any libraries? (Not that they are required.)

Comment: yeah not allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the following:

- `enumerate` is an in-built counter, you don't need to increment it yourself.
- Your indentation was incorrect, so `print` was not being applied within the loop.
- `enumerate` has an optional `start` parameter, so you can start from 1 instead of 0.

This is one solution.

```
list1 = ['John', 'Maria',',','and','Danny', 'are','#','1','surfers','.']

for count, a in enumerate(list1, 1):
    print("{0}. {1}".format(count, a))

# 1. John
# 2. Maria
# 3. ,
# 4. and
# 5. Danny
# 6. are
# 7. #
# 8. 1
# 9. surfers
# 10. .
```

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate` will produce a tuple, where the first value is the index in the loop. It starts counting at zero, so you will need to increase count by 1 if you want to start the list at one.

```
list1 = ['John', 'Maria',',','and','Danny', 'are','#','1','surfers','.']

for count, a in enumerate(list1):
    print("{}. {}".format(count+1, a))
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it. Try this:

```
for index, a in enumerate(list1):
    print('%-1d. %s' % (index + 1, a)
```

This prints:

> 1. John
> 2. Maria
> 3. ,
> 4. and
> 5. Danny
> 6. are
> 7. #
> 8. 1
> 9. surfers
> 10. .

As desired. **Note the `+1` since the indices returned by enumerate are zero-indexed!**

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` to put two lists together for *list comprehension*

```
list1 = ['John', 'Maria',',','and','Danny', 'are','#','1','surfers','.']
n = len(list1)
numbered_list_str = '\n'.join([str(i) + '. ' + x for i, x in zip(range(1, n+1), list1)])
print(numbered_list_str)
```

> 1. John
> 2. Maria
> 3. ,
> 4. and
> 5. Danny
> 6. are
> 7. #
> 8. 1
> 9. surfers
> 10. .